# Grails .save(flush: true) behaves the same with .save()

Tags: grails, groovy, hql, transactional

we have been testing a different way of saving.  However, the results weren't as we expected. We have create-survey method, and each survey has multiple questions. We tested few cases and they all committed the queries the same way.

```
@Transactional class Service {
      Survey createNewSurvey(NewSurveyCommand command) {
       Survey survey = new Survey()
       survey.properties[] = command.properties
       survey.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)  //save survey and flush
       for (NewQuestionCommand questionCommand : command.questions) {
           Question question = new Question()
           question.properties[] = questionCommand.properties
           question.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)  // save each questions and flush
       }
       return survey    } }
```

The second removing transactional and saving without flush

```
 class Service {
      Survey createNewSurvey(NewSurveyCommand command) {
       Survey survey = new Survey()
       survey.properties[] = command.properties
       survey.save()  //save survey and flush
       for (NewQuestionCommand questionCommand : command.questions) {
           Question question = new Question()
           question.properties[] = questionCommand.properties
           question.save()  // save each questions and flush
       }
       return survey    } }
```

The 3th and 4th, once with transactional and once without transactional.

```
class Service {
          Survey createNewSurvey(NewSurveyCommand command) {
           Survey survey = new Survey()
           survey.properties[] = command.properties
           survey.save()  //save survey and flush
           for (NewQuestionCommand questionCommand : command.questions) {
               Question question = new Question()
               question.properties[] = questionCommand.properties
              survey.addToQuestions()
    }
           survey.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
           return survey    } }
```

In the end from MySQL log, we checked that no matter we did all the inserting happened within one commit.

```
    Query    SET autocommit=0
    Query    insert into survey (version, brand ,...)
    Query    insert into question (version,..d)
    Query    insert into question (version,..d)
    Query    commit
    Query    SET autocommit=1
```

In the end we didn't see any difference between .save(flush: true, failOnError: true), save() ( with or without Transactional).

Could anybody explain how are `save with flush` and `without flush` working.?

[Grails doc](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html) says that flush (optional) - When set to true flushes the persistence context, persisting the object immediately. However, in our case we saw, it didn't happen as in doc says. Or did I misunderstand it?

Comment: In short, GORM/Hibernate attempts to save all your INSERT/UPDATE statements until the session flushes. This is either until you manually call `.save(flush: true)` or the session goes out of scope (e.g. final controller renders/responds). That's the default behavior. Everything above seems to be normal. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore,  when I put  .save(flush: true) after each save, I expect database logs to be as following. https://paste.ofcode.org/L8fndE865TA8htymJar82J. For each save(flush: true), one commit

Comment: You missed the keyword in both the docs and my reply ATTEMPTS. You won't be able to control the level of commits to the database using `flush: true` in such a precise manner. There are a lot of factors involved and most of the time GORM/Hibernate is going to make the best choice for you.

Comment: so you are saying that each session is not creating a new commit in the database. Commits are handled by hibernate.

Comment: You tried any without even issuing a save ? Or even a multi layered transactional where 1 calls multiple other transactionals ? typically save() is sufficient. In specific places where you want to ensure semi segment of change has gone through use .withNewTransaction and .save(flush:true) to ensure it has gone through. You obviously have not had the requirement to use flush:true so in your current scope of tests it is no different https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuekit-plugin/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=flush%3Atrue&type= you can see in these cases I had to - to ensure it got picked up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`save()` without `flush: true` **doesn't start the database connection**. After calling save() data is only persisted in Hibernate session. So in your case, you would not find any related lines in MYSQL log file.

`save(flush: true)` **starts the transaction on database level immediately.** So after calling `save(flush: true)` for the first time you should already see some lines in your MYSQL log file, probably sth like:

```
Query    SET autocommit=0
Query    insert into survey (version, brand ,...)
```

After calling `save(flush: true)` for the second time the transaction is being continued (not started again, so no `COMMIT` will happen between two saves) on database level. You can also see lines added to your MYSQL log file.